# Error when installing and running XRDP (Remote Desktop) with Gnome Ubuntu: I encounter a Black Screen

Tags: ubuntu, debian, virtual-machine, gnome, xrdp

I'm trying to connect to a remote desktop (Gnome Ubuntu) using [XRDP](http://xrdp.org/) (Remote Desktop Protocol). However, when I connect with either Apache's [Guacamole](https://guacamole.apache.org/) or Microsofts [Remote Desktop](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-remote-desktop), I encounter a black screen with a cursor.

I can verify that my Ubuntu server is running healthily through logs as well as ssh'ing in and running a test (proxmox interface).

Interestingly, when I use `xfce4` instead of `gnome`, I am able to connect. However, I can't get the terminal to work properly for some reason. If I am logged into gnome using the proxmox interface I can see the terminal popping up in my gnome session when I start it in my xfce xrdp session.

### Possible issues:

Possible issues may include my startup/installation script:

```
# placeholder for script
```

Comment: Thanks for the Q @Jalau --> I found this to be very helpful while I was debugging my remote desktop devops. I've made some changes to the Q to improve its state so that it can be reopened. I just need one last edit from you before pushing that forward --> could you please include your startup/installation script? (So that this becomes a replicable code Q instead of a hardware Q). Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I got the same problem and after many tries I solved it by:

**1)** Removing xrdp

> $sudo apt-get remove xrdp

**2)** Reinstall xrdp

> $sudo apt-get install xrdp

**3)** *Very Important* Add this lines after install:

> $echo gnome-session > ~/.xsession
>
> $chmod +x ~/.xsession

Comment: Is `chmod +x ~/.xsession` needed? Typically these files do not need x permission.

Comment: This solution does not work on Ubutu 20.04.1 LTS. Ironically, RDP and VNC behave equally bad.  Both return a black screen.

Comment: Could someone explain what writing gnome-session to the .xsession file does? I want to understand what is happening before I try it.

Comment: @GabrielFair That is something I would like to know too.

Comment: @Shrimpy Yep, didn't work for me either. 20.04 LTS.

Comment: I got a black screen

Answer (score 5):

#### 1. Remove previously installed xrdp:

```
$ sudo systemctl disable xrdp
$ sudo systemctl stop xrdp

$ sudo apt purge xrdp
$ sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-core
$ sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-input-all
$ sudo apt purge xorgxrdp
```

#### 2. Re-install xrdp & required packages:

```
$ sudo apt install xrdp
$ sudo apt install xserver-xorg-core
$ sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
$ sudo apt install xorgxrdp
```

You also need to grant access to the **/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key** file for **xrdp** user. It is available to members of the **ssl-cert** group by default.

```
$ sudo adduser xrdp ssl-cert           # add xrdp into ssl-cert group
```

```
$ sudo systemctl start xrdp            # start xrdp service
$ systemctl is-active xrdp             # display current xrdp service state
...
active
```

```
$ sudo systemctl enable xrdp           # start xrdp on system startup
```

#### 3. Reboot system:

```
$ sudo reboot
```

#### 4. Firewall configuration (optional):

You need to open access on port 3389.

```
$ sudo ufw allow 3389
```

It is more secure to open it only for your IP address or network. For example:

```
$ sudo ufw allow from 10.5.5.0/24 to any port 3389
```

The best practice is to use an SSH tunnel to connect to the remote desktop and make xRDP listen only for local connections.

#### 5. Setup your RDP-client

**Please note that in some cases the user who will connect to xRDP must log out before doing so!**

- Connect to your server using any RDP client.
- Enter the user credentials of your Ubuntu computer.
- Now you can see the remote desktop initial screen.

#### Related commands:

```
$ sudo systemctl status xrdp           # display current xrdp status

$ sudo systemctl start xrdp            # start xrdp service
$ sudo systemctl stop xrdp             # stop xrdp service
$ sudo systemctl restart xrdp          # restart xrdp service

$ sudo systemctl enable xrdp           # enable xrdp on system startup
$ sudo systemctl disable xrdp          # disable xrdp on system startup
```

Comment: I found this solution and accompanied explanations quite helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I got a black screen. `~/.xsession` contains `gnome-session`

Comment: This didn't work for me until I also did https://stackoverflow.com/a/65744987/470749 . Thanks for this answer!

Comment: Now I'm on Ubuntu 22 so I will look at https://askubuntu.com/a/1445829/48214 and https://askubuntu.com/a/1404412/48214

Answer (score 4):

This worked perfectly for me in Ubutu 20.04.1 LTS

```
echo gnome-session > ~/.xsession
chmod +x ~/.xsession
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Worked for me. In my .xsession was mate configured...

Comment: Additionally, need to monitor what kind of environment you are in! Otherwise, the `~/` file will be at root after `sudo su`=)

Answer (score 1):

I have found an alternative solution:

```sh
apt-get install x2goserver
```

This will install x2go, which is opensource remote desktop (RDP) server for Linux with `x2goclient` available both for Linux and Windows.

But I personally use chrome remote desktop. As the install was straightforward and I have never had any driver/config/software issues with it so far.